# User.Mobile is updatable, but not nullable via API

Tags: apex, api

Even if it should be, I can see attribute "nillable" on that field. I am able to null the value in web app, but when I try to push update with help of DeveloperForce.Salesforce client through API, nothing happens. However every another field for update actually is updated and response is always "Success". Also when I update the field with any value, it succeeds.

I would be grateful for any hint.

EDIT:
Does anyone know how to handle this situation or what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Your post doesn't actually contain a question.

Comment: Many tools prevent inserting null values by default. You need to check your software's documentation.